# Log in to Digg with email

Tags: login, digg

I (accidentally) created another Digg account when I signed up for Digg Reader, because I used the same (my primary) email I used for Google Reader.

Now I just realized I have two Digg accounts, one with my primary email and one with a secondary email. So I signed out.

**My question is**: how do I sign in again, with any of my email addresses as credentials? The only options I can find are Facebook and Twitter.

[image]

Comment: I experienced a similar confusing interface with Gravatar.com the other day, as if they are trying to force you to use an Open ID?! However, I eventually found a login box in which I could enter my existing (secondary) email address.

Comment: There are [a lot of people complaining](http://gigaom.com/2012/08/01/so-the-new-digg-has-relaunched-now-comes-the-hard-part/) that you can't login to the new Digg with your old email address!? (I think you can also login with a Google Account.)

Comment: @w3d Yeah saw that post, but no solution in it. Do you know where or how I can login?

Comment: From comments on that post it would seem, rather bizarrely, that you can't?! It is suggested that the developers are (or were?) planning on (re-)implementing this, to enable existing/old users to log in to their accounts, but I can't see that this has been done on the site as yet? Favouring a new FB integration/login over existing users is a massive failing - and this appears to be echo'd in the comments.